# bootstrap-select hide event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out why I can't get the close event triggered when a bootstrap-select is closed.

```js
$(function() {
    
$('.selectpicker').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    alert('hide.bs.dropdown');
})
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.2/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple="true"  data-done-button="true"  data-live-search="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `hide.bs.dropdown`event is tied to the parent of the selectpicker, instead of the selectpicker itself, so you will need to :

```js
$(function() {
    
$('#selectpicker-container').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    alert('hide.bs.dropdown');
})
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.2/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<div id="selectpicker-container">
     <select class="selectpicker" multiple="true"  data-done-button="true"  data-live-search="true">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

the bootstrap-select plugin has different events to the standard bootstrap dropdown. see [Here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/commit/541d9a06af6fc69161156a78cdb081567f2a3b03).

> rendered.bs.select, refreshed.bs.select, change.bs.select,
>   hide.bs.select, hidden.bs.select, show.bs.select, shown.bs.select
>
> hide.bs.select, hidden.bs.select, show.bs.select, and shown.bs.select
>   all have a relatedTarget property, whose value is the toggling anchor
>   element.
>
> changed.bs.select passes through event, clickedIndex, newValue,
>   oldValue. true if selected and false if not selected.

So, try:-

```
$(function() {    
    $('.selectpicker').on('hide.bs.select', function () {
        alert('hide.bs.select');
    });
});
```